# Contextmenu event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show a contextmenu with the library contextMenu.js when right clicking on a div.

This is what i have now:

```
$( ".sc_Bar" ).contextmenu(function() {
    console.log("ok");
    $(this).contextMenu(menu);
    return false;
});
```

The event is firing but the menu dont appear.

When I change the event to a clickevent its working.

```
$( ".sc_Bar" ).click(function() {
    console.log("ok");
    $(this).contextMenu(menu);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: http://ignitersworld.com/lab/contextMenu.html#optionDoc ( `mouseClick` option), http://ignitersworld.com/lab/contextMenu.html#browserOverride

Comment: thanks, this works fine @CBroe